# autenticacion JWT con el access_token en el header

Tags: jwt

Hay alguna forma de obtener el usuario logeado con JWT llevando el access_token en el header?
Es decir, tener la posibilidad de obtener el usuario en cuestion haciendo un get a /auth/user solo con la authorization: bearer access_token en el header.

Tengo un fallo de seguridad en mi aplicacion ya que al llamar al metodo post a /users me devuelve todos los datos de los users (passwords e emails incluidos).

Este es el codigo para la auntenticacion:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const User = require("../models/User");
const Token = require("../models/Token");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const user = await User.findById(id);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use("local",  new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: "email",
  passwordField: "password",
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user || !user.comparePassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect email or password.'});
  }
  done(null, user, {message: 'Logged In Successfully'})
}));

passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey   : 'your_jwt_secret'
},
function (jwtPayload, cb) {
  console.log(jwtPayload)
  Token.findById(jwtPayload._id)
      .then(token => {
          console.log(token);
          if(!token) {
              return cb(null, false, {message:'Invalid Token'});
          }
          //find the user in db if needed
          User.findById(jwtPayload.userId)
              .then(user => {
                  return cb(null, user);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  return cb(err);
              });    })
      .catch(err => {
          return cb(err);
      });
}));
```

Este es el codigo para las rutas del login y el registro:

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const User = require("../../models/User");
const Token = require("../../models/Token");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

// POST /register
router.post("/register", async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).send({error: "Missing username or password or email"});
  }
  const existingEmail = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  const existingUsername = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

  if (existingEmail || existingUsername) {
    return res.status(403).send({error: "Account already exists with email or username"});
  }

  const user = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  await user.save();
  return res.send({message: "Successfully registered"});

});


router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    session: false,
  })
);
router.post("/login", async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Login failed"
    });
  };
  const newToken = new Token({
    userId: req.user.id
  })
  const savedToken = await newToken.save();
  const token = jwt.sign(savedToken.getJWT(), 'your_jwt_secret');
  return res.json({token});
});

router.post('/logout', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}));
router.post('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  Token.deleteMany({
    userId: req.user.id
  }).then(() => {
    res.send({message: "Successfully invalidated Tokens for user"})
  }).catch(()=>{
    next();
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: hola ,agrega mas informacion , como imagenes,codigo ,etc para poderte brindarte ayuda..gracias

Comment: Hola, ya añadi mi codigo

Answer (score -1):

Depende de los claim añadidos en la generación del JWT

Te dejo un ejemplo

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

En este caso en el payload esta añadida esta información

```
    {
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

Lo puedes comprobar en https://jwt.io/